# Redirect nohup to stdout on a script

Tags: python, linux, unix, nohup

I have a `.sh` script that via `nohup` runs a lot of Python scripts.

I use `nohup` to run them in the background and avoid neccesary *enter* pressing when the "*nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'*" message appears.

```
nohup python script2.py 2> /dev/null &
nohup python script2.py 2> /dev/null &
[...]
```

When I run this `.sh`, I get the two Python scripts running in the background, ok.

This Python scripts generate a log file, which I deriver to `std.stdout`:

```
stream_config = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)  <-- here
stream_config.setFormatter(formatter)
importer_logger.addHandler(stream_config)
```

Due to my implementation, I want to launch those `nohup` but sending the stdout to to PID 1

I can do this easily without using `nohup` as follows:

```
python tester.py > /proc/1/fd/1
```

But how can I combine that "*don't press enter to continue*" and "*deriver the file to stdout*"?

I tried these with no luck:

```
nohup python tester.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2> /dev/null &
nohup python tester.py 2> /proc/1/fd/1 &
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your command by using the shell to indirectly start your program so that you can redirect its output rather than the output of nohup:

```
nohup bash -c "exec python tester.py > /proc/1/fd/1" 2> /dev/null &
```

This isn't the best option but it at least corrects the issue that made your attempts fail.